# PowerShell Active Directory - Compare Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership to array of group names

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've written a script that our provisioning team uses to manage terminated users and group memberships.
The script works well, but it takes a long time due to how I chose to enumerate group memberships to begin with.
The current script uses `Get-ADGroup $group -pr Members | select -ExpandProperty Members` to enumerate membership.

I figure there has to be a more efficient method of doing this, so I wrote this:

```
  $grpMemberships = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name
  foreach ($Group in $Groups){
         if ($grpMemberships -contains $group) {
         Write-Host "$grpMembership found!"
         Remove-ADGroupMember $grpMembership -members $user
         Write-Host "Removing $user from $grpMembership"
         "$user is a member of $group" | out-file -filepath Termed_Users-$get-date -f yyy-MM-dd.txt -Append
         Write-Host ""
         }
         }
```

The problem is that this never seems to execute. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: How did you define the variable `$Groups`?  If I'm not wrong you should use `if ($grpMemberships.name -contains $group)`  or depending on how you defined the variable `if ($grpMemberships.name -contains $group.name)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I defined $Groups as  $Groups = @("group1”, “group2”) so it's an array of strings vs the array of objects. I'm mobile at the moment, but as soon as I'm back at a PC I'll try your suggestion and let you know how it turns out!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf)
I figured it out with your assistance.

```
foreach ($grpMembership in $grpMemberships.name) {
    foreach ($Group in $Groups){
        if ($Groups -contains $grpMembership) {
            Write-Host "$grpMembership found!"
            #Remove-ADGroupMember $grpMembership -members $user
            Write-Host "Removing $user from $grpMembership"
            "$user is a member of $group" | out-file -filepath Termed_Users-$(get-date -f yyy-MM-dd).txt -Append
            Write-Host ""
        }
    }
}
```